# How to make a recyclerview show only one array depending on a percantage?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

i want a recyclerview to show only one array, but having more of them in the arraylist. The one that has to be shown can't always be the same, but it will depend on some percentages.

Eg.: the 1st array has 20% of chances, the 2nd 50% and the 3rd 50% percent too. And randomly one will be shown. But when i refresh the screen it will change.

I suppose that what i should do is to set percentages to every single array on the arraylist, but i don't know how to do it and what to do next.

That's my java file.

```java
public class Comida extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pickEntidad();
    }
    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And that is the adapter:

```java
public class Adaptador  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador.ViewHolder> //implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private List<Entidad> listItems;
    private OnRecipeListener mOnRecipeListener;

    public  Adaptador(List<Entidad> listItems, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mOnRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, parent, false);
        //view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolder(view, mOnRecipeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
        int resource = listItems.get(position).getImgFoto();
        String title = listItems.get(position).getTitulo();
        String time = listItems.get(position).getTiempo();
        int barra = listItems.get(position).getRating();
        int fondo = listItems.get(position).getColorfondo();
        viewholder.setData(resource, title, time, barra, fondo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ImageView imgFoto;
        private TextView titulo;
        private TextView tiempo;
        private RatingBar ratingBar;
        private ImageView colorfondo;
        OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
            super(itemView);

            imgFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
            tiempo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);
            ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarVerd);
            colorfondo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorfondo);
            this.onRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        private void setData(int resource, String title, String time, int barra, int fondo){
            imgFoto.setImageResource(resource);
            titulo.setText(title);
            tiempo.setText(time);
            ratingBar.setRating(barra);
            colorfondo.setImageResource(fondo);

        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onRecipeListener.OnRecipe(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

    public interface OnRecipeListener{
        void OnRecipe(int position);
    }
}
```

Here there is the Entidad file:

```java
public class Entidad2 {

    private int imgFoto;
    private String titulo;
    private String tiempo;
    private int ratingBar;
    private int colorfondo;

    public Entidad2(int imgFoto, String titulo, String tiempo, int ratingBar, int colorfondo) {

        this.imgFoto = imgFoto;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.tiempo = tiempo;
        this.ratingBar = ratingBar;
        this.colorfondo = colorfondo;
    }

    public int getImgFoto() {
        return imgFoto;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getTiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    public int getRating() { return ratingBar; }

    public int getColorfondo() {
        return colorfondo;
    }
}
```

Please if anyone has any idea of how to do it, tell me.
And in case you need more code just tell me,

thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSyH2.png)

Here @Emir look if it is inside

```java
public class Comida extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, R.drawable.color_carnes, 50));
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, R.drawable.color_carnes, 200));
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, R.drawable.color_carnes, 350));


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        Adaptador2 Adaptador2 = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(Adaptador2);
        Adaptador2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pickEntidad();
    }
    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int position) {

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(351);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        Adaptador2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to show a single Entidad object from your Entidad list randomly with different show chances.

Ex: Create an integer field named Priority on your Entidad object. Set the first Entidad's priority to 50, the second 200, the third 350.Create the following method to randomly pick depending on priority.(Save references of your Entidad objects on your mainactivity after you create them.)

Edit: Entidad.java

```
public class Entidad {

private int imgFoto;
private String titulo;
private String tiempo;
private int ratingBar;
private int colorfondo;
private int priority;

public Entidad(int imgFoto, String titulo, String tiempo, int ratingBar, int colorfondo, int priority) {
    this.imgFoto = imgFoto;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.tiempo = tiempo;
    this.ratingBar = ratingBar;
    this.colorfondo = colorfondo;
    this.priority = priority;
}

public int getRatingBar() {
    return ratingBar;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public int getImgFoto() {
    return imgFoto;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public String getTiempo() {
    return tiempo;
}

public int getRating() { return ratingBar; }

public int getColorfondo() {
    return colorfondo;
}
}
```

Edit 2: Use of the getEntidad()

```
public class Comida extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador.OnRecipeListener {
private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
List<Entidad> listItems;
Adaptador adaptor;
private Entidad entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

    recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
//Initialize entidad objects and keep references of them to use in pickEntidad() method

   entidad1 = new Entidad(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, R.drawable.color_carnes,50);
   entidad2 = new Entidad(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, R.drawable.color_carnes,200);
    entidad3 = new Entidad(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, R.drawable.color_carnes,350);

    listItems.add(entidad1);
    listItems.add(entidad2); 
    listItems.add(entidad3);

    adaptor = new Adaptador(listItems, this);
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptador);
    adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
//Call pickEntidad() to randomly pick one entidad and show on the list
    pickEntidad();
}

@Override
public void OnRecipe(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
}
private void pickEntidad(){
//Generates random int value between 0-350
final int random = new Random().nextInt(351);

//get priorities from your created Entidad objects.
int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


listItems.clear()

//Pick one randomly depending on priority
if(random < priority1){

listItems.add(entidad1)

}else if(random < priority2){

listItems.add(entidad2)

}else if (random <= priority3){

listItems.add(entidad3)

}

//update your adapter

adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
}
```

Each time you want to refresh your list, call this pickEntidad() method. This is a hardcoded approach though, would be useless if you have too many items and do not know the priority values or the range. You can also set your item priorities randomly by generating an int between 0-351. Hope I understood your question correctly.

Also, don't give variables names with capital latters. Changed your 'Adaptor' variable into 'adaptor'

Comment: I've added the Entidad file here in the post, but i don't understant clearly if what you have written must be in the MainActivity.java, or in the Entidad. And i don't understand what you mean with integer file. Please help and thanks   @eyildirimdev

Comment: @cristianoronaldo add the pickEntidad() method inside MainActivity.java. Add the edited section to the Entidad.java

Comment: Ok i know where the two last edits you did go, but about the first one i don't know where to put it, could you show to whole code where it should be. And what about the Adapter, there's nothing new on it. Thanks @Emir

Comment: Please i've done what you said, but i don't know where you took entidad1, entidad2 and entidad3 from? Could you tell me, i'd like to see the whole MainActivity.java just to make sure. @Emir

Comment: Thanks Emir it's almost finished but now two error messages appear, i've added a picture of it at the end of my post. Thank you.

Comment: The second error: notifyDataSetChanged-Non-static method 'notifyDataSetChanged()' cannot be referenced from a static context- remains. Do you know what to do?

Comment: put the pickEntidad() method inside Comida class. I think its outside of it. look at the braces and you will see

Comment: it is already inside look at the last code i've just added to the post

Comment: did you rename your Adaptor2 with adaptor? if not please add the changes in the last edit

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Emir it is really pleasant to find people like you who really care about helping others to solve their problems and make stackoverflow better. I hope to find someone like you in the future in case i had a problem. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, I am having fun! Glad I could help. An upvote would not hurt too :P

Comment: Sorry Emir I had not look at it before but now that I've checked it i had a method on the MainActivity.java which i want it to make that if the entidad1 appears it takes me to x activity, and if entidad2 appears to y activity and so, any idea of how to do it, because now it takes me all the time to the activity of the entidad1. I guess it must be related with using priority to decide which to open instead of the position. Thanks Emir.

Comment: yes, position will always be the same, you can decide what to open using priority or create another field in Entidad class and call it "id", you can identify your objects using setId() and getId(). I suggest you to open another question for further discussion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395703/how-to-set-an-onclicklistener-on-a-recyclerview-not-depending-on-the-position look at it Emir and help me please