# How to set an OnClickListener on a recyclerview not depending on the position

Tags: java

I want the onclicklistener method to open the activity which is related to the object:entidad1, entidad2 or entidad3.

The OnRecipe method on the MainActivity.java which i want it to make that if the entidad1 appears it takes me to x activity, and if entidad2 appears to y activity and so, any idea of how to do it, because now it takes me all the time to the activity of the entidad1. I guess it must be related with using priority to decide which to open instead of the position.

That's my Adapter:

```java
package com.test.platos_4;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class Adaptador2  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador2.ViewHolder>
{
    private List<Entidad2> listItems;
    private OnRecipeListener mOnRecipeListener;

    public  Adaptador2(List<Entidad2> listItems, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.mOnRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista2, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, mOnRecipeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
        int resource = listItems.get(position).getImgFoto();
        String title = listItems.get(position).getTitulo();
        String time = listItems.get(position).getTiempo();
        int barra = listItems.get(position).getRating();
        //int fondo = listItems.get(position).getColorfondo();
        viewholder.setData(resource, title, time, barra);
        // por si necesito color de fondo viewholder.setData(resource, title, time, barra, fondo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ImageView imgFoto;
        private TextView titulo;
        private TextView tiempo;
        private RatingBar ratingBar;
        //private ImageView colorfondo;
        OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
            super(itemView);

            imgFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
            tiempo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);
            ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarVerd);
            //colorfondo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorfondo);
            this.onRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //por si necesito color de fondo private void setData(int resource, String title, String time, int barra, int fondo){
        private void setData(int resource, String title, String time, int barra){
            imgFoto.setImageResource(resource);
            titulo.setText(title);
            tiempo.setText(time);
            ratingBar.setRating(barra);
            //colorfondo.setImageResource(fondo);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onRecipeListener.OnRecipe(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnRecipeListener{
        void OnRecipe(int priority);
    }
}
```

And that is the MainActivity.java:

```java
public class Comida extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pickEntidad();
    }
    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And the Entidad.java:

```java
public class Entidad2 {

    private int imgFoto;
    private String titulo;
    private String tiempo;
    private int ratingBar;
    private int priority;
    private int d;


    public Entidad2(int imgFoto, String titulo, String tiempo, int ratingBar, int priority) {

        this.imgFoto = imgFoto;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.tiempo = tiempo;
        this.ratingBar = ratingBar;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public int getImgFoto() {
        return imgFoto;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public String getTiempo() {
        return tiempo;
    }

    public int getRating() { return ratingBar; }

    public  int getPriority() {
        return  priority;
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve the problem and if you need more information just tell me i will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to differentiate your items by Priority but you are passing item position from your adapter to your activity. You need to pass clicked item's Priority instead of its position. I have changed your Adaptor2 class

```
package com.test.platos_4;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class Adaptador2  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador2.ViewHolder>
{
private List<Entidad2> listItems;
private OnRecipeListener mOnRecipeListener;

public  Adaptador2(List<Entidad2> listItems, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.mOnRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista2, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view, mOnRecipeListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
    Entidad2 entidad = listItems.get(position);
    int resource = entidad.getImgFoto();
    String title = entidad.getTitulo();
    String time = entidad.getTiempo();
    int barra = entidad.getRating();
    final int priority = entidad.getPriority();
    //int fondo = listItems.get(position).getColorfondo();
    viewholder.setData(resource, title, time, barra);

//You can pass the clicked item's priority back to your activity like this
    viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    mOnRecipeListener.OnRecipe(priority);
        }
    });
    // por si necesito color de fondo viewholder.setData(resource, title, time, barra, fondo);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView imgFoto;
    private TextView titulo;
    private TextView tiempo;
    private RatingBar ratingBar;
    //private ImageView colorfondo;
    OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
        super(itemView);

        imgFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
        titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        tiempo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);
        ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarVerd);
        //colorfondo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorfondo);

        //This is useless
        //this.onRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;

    }

    //por si necesito color de fondo private void setData(int resource, String title, String time, int barra, int fondo){
    private void setData(int resource, String title, String time, int barra){
        imgFoto.setImageResource(resource);
        titulo.setText(title);
        tiempo.setText(time);
        ratingBar.setRating(barra);
        //colorfondo.setImageResource(fondo);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

public interface OnRecipeListener{
    void OnRecipe(int priority);
}
}
```

Comment: OMG it worked! Next time i have a problem i'll leave the llink below so that you notice that i have post it if you don't care Emir. You are the best.

Comment: Anytime! Glad I can help.

Comment: Emir could you look to this new question i've post, i need help to solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480562/how-to-use-a-searchview-out-of-the-toolbar-and-without-the-recyclerview-being-sh