# How to use a searchview without the recyclerview being showed all the time?

Tags: java, android-studio

I've an activity with some buttons that don't have anything to do with that, and also a searchview inside a RelativeLayout on the top. What I want is that when I write on the searchview, the recyclerview arrays appear on the screen, but that when i'm not writing anything appears, just the buttons i told you before.

What i did to avoid the recyclerView to be shown when the searchview is not being used is to set 0dp in it's width and height parameters.

That is my MainActivity.java:

```java
public class Dishes extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    Button boton_verdura;
    Button boton_carne;
    Button boton_pasta;
    Button boton_sopas;
    Button boton_pescados;
    Button boton_ensaladas;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dishes);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        boton_verdura=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_verduras);
        boton_carne=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_carnes);
        boton_pasta=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_pasta);
        boton_sopas=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_sopas);
        boton_pescados=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_pescados);
        boton_ensaladas=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_ensaladas);

        boton_verdura.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(Dishes.this,Verduras.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        boton_carne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(Dishes.this,Carnes.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        boton_pasta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(Dishes.this,Pasta.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        boton_sopas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(Dishes.this,Sopas.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        boton_pescados.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(Dishes.this,Pescados.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        boton_ensaladas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent in = new Intent(Dishes.this,Ensaladas.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.lv_prueba);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        List<Entidad2> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.add(new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Calabacines", " 10 min.", 4, R.drawable.color_ensaladas));
        listItems.add(new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Patatas", " 15 min.", 2, R.drawable.color_ensaladas));
        listItems.add(new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Tomates", " 2 min.", 5, R.drawable.color_ensaladas));

        Adaptador2 Adaptador2 = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(Adaptador2);
        Adaptador2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int position) {

        if(position == 0){
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Judias_verdes.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if(position == 1){
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Sardinas_fritas.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.example_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Adaptador2.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my Mainactivity.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffff00"
    tools:context=".Dishes">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/rv_buscar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/line"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

            </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_sopas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_sopa_15"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo_sopa_15"
                android:text="   Sopas"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:fontFamily="@font/san_francisco_display_regular"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_pescados"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_pescado3_30_15"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo_pescado3_30_15"
                android:text="   Pescados"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:fontFamily="@font/san_francisco_display_regular"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_ensaladas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_ensalada3_30_15"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo_ensalada3_30_15"
                android:text="   Ensaladas"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:fontFamily="@font/san_francisco_display_regular"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_carnes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_filete_30_15"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo_filete_30_15"
                android:text="   Carnes"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:fontFamily="@font/san_francisco_display_regular"
                tools:ignore="DuplicateIds,HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_verduras"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_vegetables_30_15"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo_vegetables_30_15"
                android:text="   Verduras"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:fontFamily="@font/san_francisco_display_regular"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/boton_pasta"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_pizza_30_15"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo_pizza_30_15"
                android:text="   Pasta"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fontFamily="@font/san_francisco_display_regular"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,MissingConstraints" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lv_prueba"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And that is the Adaptor.java:

```java
ackage com.test.platos_4;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Adaptador2  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador2.ViewHolder> implements Filterable
{
    private List<Entidad2> listItems;
    private List<Entidad2> listItemsFull;
    private OnRecipeListener mOnRecipeListener;

    public  Adaptador2(List<Entidad2> listItems, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        listItemsFull = new ArrayList<>(listItems);
        this.mOnRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista2, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, mOnRecipeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewholder, int position) {
        int resource = listItems.get(position).getImgFoto();
        String title = listItems.get(position).getTitulo();
        String time = listItems.get(position).getTiempo();
        int barra = listItems.get(position).getRating();
        final int priority = listItems.get(position).getPriority();
        //int fondo = listItems.get(position).getColorfondo();
        viewholder.setData(resource, title, time, barra);

        //You can pass the clicked item's priority back to your activity like this
        viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mOnRecipeListener.OnRecipe(priority);
            }
        });
        // por si necesito color de fondo viewholder.setData(resource, title, time, barra, fondo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }

    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Entidad2> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(listItemsFull);
            }
            else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Entidad2 item : listItemsFull) {
                    if (item.getTitulo().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            listItems.clear();
            listItems.addAll((List)results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ImageView imgFoto;
        private TextView titulo;
        private TextView tiempo;
        private RatingBar ratingBar;
        //private ImageView colorfondo;
        OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, OnRecipeListener onRecipeListener) {
            super(itemView);

            imgFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
            tiempo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);
            ratingBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarVerd);
            //colorfondo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorfondo);
            // this.onRecipeListener = onRecipeListener;

        }

        //por si necesito color de fondo private void setData(int resource, String title, String time, int barra, int fondo){
        private void setData(int resource, String title, String time, int barra){
            imgFoto.setImageResource(resource);
            titulo.setText(title);
            tiempo.setText(time);
            ratingBar.setRating(barra);
            //colorfondo.setImageResource(fondo);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }

    public interface OnRecipeListener{
        void OnRecipe(int priority);
    }
}
```

But an error appears:
[image]

Please help I'm not sure of what to do because i've never used a SearchView, so any help will be useful.

Thanks

The new problem appearing when i try to get into the activity while running the app:

```java
08-14 16:33:07.115 17470-17470/com.test.platos_4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.platos_4, PID: 17470
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView
        at com.test.platos_4.Dishes.onCreateOptionsMenu(Dishes.java:136)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3546)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:328)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1370)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1650)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:134)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6815)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
08-14 16:33:07.119 17470-17470/com.test.platos_4 E/MQSEventManagerDelegate: failed to get MQSService.
```

Comment: I don't see any code about searchView, do you seek help for that or did you try something that does not work?

Comment: Emir I've changed the code almost completely and I think it is what i want it and it will do what i expected, but the error i've post at the end of the post doesn't allow me to run the app. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: @cristianoronaldo rather than continuing to edit this same question, you should in the future ask new more specific questions about each error you have... The latest error you showed is likely from your MainActivity importing the wrong SearchView

Answer (score 1):

the `getFilter()` error you see is because you are trying to call `getFilter()` on Adaptador2, but since `getFilter()` isn't a static method you need to call it on an instance of the adapter, not the adapter class like `someInstanceOfAdapterClass.getFilter()`

One main issue is that your naming your adaptador class instance with the same name as the class which is a really bad idea... On these lines here:

```
Adaptador2 Adaptador2 = new Adaptador2(listItems, this); // this is bad
recyclerView.setAdapter(Adaptador2);
Adaptador2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you want to rename the variable to something different then the class name, a common thing to do would be to use a lowercase. You'll also need to keep track of it in your activities variables so it can be accessed in onCreateOptionsMenu so do something like this:

```
// at the top of your main activity define it
private Adaptador2 adaptador2;
```

```
// create your instance of it 
adaptador2 = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptador2);
adaptador2.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

```
// in onCreateOptionsMenu use lower case one to reference the object instance not 
// the class 
adaptador2.getFilter().filter(newText);
```

---

(I haven't tested this but it may work)

As for hiding the recycler view, you could just do something in your onQueryChanged method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // this will hide your recycler anytime the search query is empty
    // and show it anytime there is a search query
    if (newText == "") {
        recyclerView.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
    } else {
        recyclerView.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    adaptador2.getFilter().filter(newText);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's solved. But my main problem is that i want the recyclerview to be shown only when using the searchbar, if not i don't want it to appear.

Comment: @cristianoronaldo updated my answer with an attempt to fix it, though I haven't actually tried it so not sure if it will work how you want